# Extract href link from html in python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I get this output list of html

```
<a href="https://www.appfutura.com/developers/hypersense-software">HyperSense Software</a>
<a href="https://www.appfutura.com/developers/qsstechnosoft">QSS Technosoft - A CMMI Level 3 Certified Company</a>
```

and more in the same format I need to extract href link from them?

**My code**

```
mainurl="https://www.appfutura.com/app-developers"
html = urlopen(mainurl).read()
main_soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
allurl=main_soup.find_all('h3')
for i in allurl:
    for a in i :
        print(a)
```

How can I extract href in this loop?

Comment: I found the solution !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way using css selector

```
urllist=[]
mainurl="https://www.appfutura.com/app-developers"
html = urlopen(mainurl).read()
main_soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
elms = main_soup.select("h3 a")
for i in elms:
    urllist.append(i.attrs["href"])
print(urllist)
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You're close. One small change in your for loop:

```py
for i in allurl:
    print(i.a["href"])
```

This gets the child with tag "a" and then the "href" attribute for that tag.

If you aren't sure how many "a" tags there are in each "h3" block, or there are more than one, you can use another for loop (or depending on what you're doing, list comprehensions):

```py
for i in allurl:
    aa = i.find_all('a')
    for j in aa:
        print(j["href"])
```